# Backbone .groupBy or filter?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Please how can I make group of items filtred for each product ? Or How can I filter items with data from categories ?

```
var Categories = new Backbone.Collection();

Categories.add([
  { title: 'category 1', category_type: 'category 1' },
  { title: 'category 2', category_type: 'category 1' },
]);

var Items = new Backbone.Collection();

Items.add([
  { title: 'Product 1', category: 'category 1' },
  { title: 'Product 2', category: 'category 1' },
  { title: 'Product 3', category: 'category 2' }
]);


var byFiltred = Items.groupBy('category');

var filtred = new Backbone.Collection(byFiltred['category 1']);

console.log(filtred.pluck('title'));
```

Thanks for opinions and answers !!
Makromat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to get. `.groupBy` returns a hierarchical object, while `.filter` (or just `.where`) an array of items matching your criteria.

So given with this array:

```
var a = [
  { title: 'Product 1', category: 'category 1' },
  { title: 'Product 2', category: 'category 1' },
  { title: 'Product 3', category: 'category 2' }
]
_.groupBy( a, 'category' );
/* returns
   { 
      "category 1" : [  { title: 'Product 1', category: 'category 1' }, { title: 'Product 2', category: 'category 1' } ],
      "category 2" : [ { title: 'Product 3', category: 'category 2' } ]
   }
*/

 _.where( a, { 'category': 'category 1' });

 /* returns
    [  { title: 'Product 1', category: 'category 1' }, { title: 'Product 2', category: 'category 1' } ]
 */
```

To display a hierarchical view, like

```
 category 1
     product 1
     product 2
 category 2
     product 1
```

You should use `.groupBy` then loop over the object and display items in each category:

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/zGsLL/)**

Comment: So I need make view with accordion style so name (tab) will be category title and content is filtred items collection. So I need make some template where will be for each category filtred items based on data from category collection ...You know what I mean ?  hope this will be helpful not only for me ... Thanks again

Comment: @Makromat look at my edit and if this is what you're going at I can provide more details.

Comment: But maybe I will do like this. I wanna make this from two json files... One items.json and one categories.json .... I building something like store system but maybe will be better make only one json file what do you mean ?

Comment: @Makromat of course, `var byWhat ="key"; _.groupBy( a, byWhat );`.

Comment: Pawel and I have last question, Can I filter this groups ? I mean when  Is in group example item with data active : false or active: true ?

Comment: You know I have groups (Categories) and when is in this category active item or inactive is showed in this group or not ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Backbone.Collection.filter()` and provide a comparator matching your category.

http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Comment: Thanks for answer yes I see this but I don't know how can I make this ... Can you send me only some sample ? I will be very grateful !!